# script to do clipping mask of bulk images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actionscript

Steps that I follows:

Open Photoshop – No documents are open. I click “Record” in actions I open my phone.PSD file (which opens up in a tab).

I open the .jpeg files (11 files at a time which open up in their respective tabs)

I click Ctrl+Tab in my phone.psd tab to move to my 1st jpeg file. I select all & copy.

On my phone.psd tab I do paste of my copied jpeg into a layer above my sleeve layer.

I then do clip mask to create “Create clipping mask” (the jpeg is now shown on the phone layer shape).

I save the work done in the .psd to web -> File -> Save for web -> .jpg

I then delete the clipped jpeg layer on my phone.psd file which makes it ready for clipping of next jpeg.

I then do Ctrl+Tab to move to the jpeg which I had just clipped & close the tab.

Recording ends.

Now, the problem is that whenever I run this batch, the batch runs fine BUT Photoshop renames the files with the same name and overwrites the previous clipped jpeg. The end result is that only the last clipped jpeg is available and that too with the 1st jpeg name.

Can any body help me what is wrong or this is possible via js coding? or in action method.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell PS how to rename the files it creates, when running a batch action, through the file renaming options.

File > Automate > Batch

[image: batch]

Select your action, destination, file naming, and any other options you want in the above menu.

For instance, see how I set up my file naming below:

[image: naming]

Comment: Hello there, I have just one issue that is how to change image name with  the name of clipped mask name that I have clipped to phone cover I have many image that I want to use for phone cover and I want to rename my final procust with the name image that have been clipped and replaced phone back cover

Comment: @Mirzaabdulrahman well now you're just getting crazy! haha  I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Mirzaabdulrahman - you may want to look into scripting Photoshop - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: @Mirzaabdulrahman You could get away with very little scripting though. You can record launching a script in a PS `Action`. So, you could do everything as you've done so far, but replace the recorded `Save` or `Export` in the action with you opening a script that saves the file. [The script could look something like this](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/0d04dfcf434d5d9db75b).